# If a function has a continuous derivative, yet is disjoint at a point, do we say that point has a derivative?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

There have been MANY variations of this question answered elsewhere, but I could find no example of this particular question, and it's important:

Say you have a piecewise function defined by different functions on different domain intervals.  At the point where the two intervals meet:

-> The function value is well defined

-> The derivative of that function is the same from the left and the right, therefore it is continuous

-> But the function itself is not continuous at that point - it has a break.

Do we say the derivative exists at that point?

For a concrete example:

y = 0 if x < 0

y = cos x if x >= 0

In this example, at the point x=0, the derivative of y = cos x is - sin x = -sin 0 = 0.  And the derivative of y = 0 is always 0.  So the derivative, y', is continuous across x = 0.  It is the same slope from the right or the left side.

BUT, at x = 0, the graph itself is at 1, but jumps to 0 on the left - it is defined at 0 but discontinuous.

So when a function is discontinuous (but defined) at a point, yet the derivative IS continuous at that point (same from both directions), do we say the derivative at that point exists?  Note in this case it is not a multiple valued function - the point at 0 is well defined - it equals 1.

This question can be generalized:  if at a given point, the Nth derivative of a function is not continuous, do we consider the (N+i)th derivative at that point for all i to also be undefined?

Thanks so much for your thoughts.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> In a word, _no_. You can check that the definition, a limit of difference quotients, does not exist at that point (and are welcome to post your own answer if you like).

Comment: If your definition of the derivative is $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, note that the numerator is $f(x+h)-f(x)$, not $f(x+h)-\lim_{t \to x}f(t)$. So continuity is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a differentiable function is always continuous (this is well known and you can check it in many books), and *differentiable* is the same as *the derivative exists at any point*. Therefore, if a function is not continuous at one point, then the derivative does not exist at that point. Simple as that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Markdown isn't quite LaTeX, so we use asterisks to do italics; for example, `*differentiable*` yields *differentiable*. (That term is probably preferable to "derivable.")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).